# Cant install SBT in AWS CodeBuild Install Phase

Tags: amazon-web-services, sbt, aws-codepipeline, buildspec

Im working with CodePipeline and Codebuild, when i set my buildspec.yml with the commands the process gives error while trying to add the Lines in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto8

    commands:
      #Install Sbt
      #- echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | tee -a  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
      - echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
      - echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt_old.list
      - curl -sL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823" | sudo apt-key add
      - apt-get update
      - apt-get install -y sbt
```

Error is the Following [Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7LnT.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is currently the correct way to install sbt in codebuild.
The error is transient; try again later.